# Raspbian automatic login (except when it shouldn't)

Tags: raspbian

**tl;dr** Can I override the auto-login feature sometimes, to log in as root?

My Pi is running Raspbian Jessie and acting as a kiosk in a public location. For this reason I have renamed the `pi` user and removed `sudo` privileges.

To get auto-login working I used the `raspi-config` command, boot options, CLI auto-login, to generate an autologin service file in `/etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service` and changed the username in that file. This works great.

Normally I will use `ssh` to remotely administer it, but in case of network failure I'd like the ability to log in locally.

However even if I `exit` from the terminal it logs me right back in. Is there a way to override this and log in as root?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered I can use the keyboard combination CTRL+Alt+Fn (F1-F7) to switch between different virtual terminals. Only the first terminal (F1) will automatically login, so I can use different credentials on the others.

However I don't think this is documented behaviour. I believe that service file should run on all virtual terminals and not just the first one, so if behaviour changes in the future then [this guide for Arch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253928/how-to-configure-agetty-to-autologon-on-only-one-terminal) might be relevant:

```
Create a new file for terminal 1 '/lib/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service' and copy into it the config you defined above.

In /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service use the following:

ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM

Console 1 will autologin [..] all other consoles will prompt for credentials.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your kiosk is using GUI: LightDM has a configuration parameter called `autologin-user-timeout`. This is usually set to zero, meaning the autologin is triggered automatically. Setting it to a non-zero value (e.g. `autologin-user-timeout=10`) will give you a chance to type in your username and password at startup.

If have command line access, you don't have to log out to change users. Simply run `su` as the autologged-in user and you will be asked for a `root` password. Typing `exit` once you're done will log you out as `root` and return you to the user terminal.